# How to install the latest fancybox via NPM

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I installed fancybox via NPM these ways:

```
npm i -D @fancyapps/ui
npm i -D @fancyapps/fancybox
```

and I now see fancybox in my devDependencies of my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "@fancyapps/ui": "^4.0.31",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",....
  },
```

however when I have this in my .js file:

```
console.log(Fancybox);
```

the console says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Fancybox is not defined
```

How can I correctly install fancybox via NPM?

Answer (score 0):

Installing with NPM CLI does not mean it magically know what you are using, you still need to import it. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-npm-and-import-export-modules-in-javascript-31a7f66a2064